# Creating a Summary Tracking Report from Details

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to create a summary monthly tracking report from detailed data. A sample of the data is as follows:

> Company    | Country | Join Date
>   Company A  |  USA    | 1/1/2011
>   Company B  | Ireland | 5/5/2011
>   Company C  | Italy   | 7/11/2011
>   Company D  | Germany | 6/14/2011

I need to create a report that would give me the number of members that joined in a given month from a given country, in the format below:

> Country 1    |   Total (January)  |   Total (Feb) | Total (Mar, etc)   |Sum (Monthly Totals)
>   Country 2    |   Total (January)  |   Total (Feb) | Total (Mar, etc)   |Sum (Monthly Totals)
>   Country 3    |   Total (January)  |   Total (Feb) | Total (Mar, etc)   |Sum (Monthly Totals)

At the bottom of each column I would need the sum for each month for all countries. Also, this report would need to be a rolling report, so when the user generates it, it will provide the most recent information.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to do this in two parts.

First, you're going to want to get the relevant data from the database.  Probably best accomplished by a statement such as:

```
SELECT country, year(join_date) as year, month(join_date) as month, count(*)
FROM trackingTable
WHERE join_date between :start_date and :end_date
GROUP BY country, year(join_date), month(join_date)
ORDER BY country, year, month
```

For your given data, this will generate the following sample:

```
Country    Year   Month  Count
==================================
Germany    2011   6      1
Ireland    2011   5      1
Italy      2011   7      1
USA        2011   1      1
```

Second (and I'm assuming that you're creating/formatting the report in an outside language), read through the data sequentially.  Given the `ORDER BY`, each country will be a separate sequence.  Psuedo-code for your needs:

```
for each row in set {
   if different country {
      total up row, start new line
   }
   add month cell to column;
   add month cell to month grand total;
}
total up grand total row, print/save
```